# Cannot change address Range 10.42.0.x in 'Shared to other computer' Method

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ethernet, lan

I have a raspberry pi 1 B+ and My Kubuntu 18.04 in place. Now I need to connect them to the same network. I used Ethernet (Not crossover cable) cable for direct connection

These are my Settings

**IPv4 Settings**
 [image: IPv4 settings]
**IPv6 settings**
 [image: IPv6 settings]

As in the image, I clearly see that I didn't provide any IP address or subnet info.

But after the connection is set up, `10.42.0.x` (in my case `10.42.0.1` and `10.42.0.226`) is the IP address.

My questions are,

1. How do I change it?
2. Is this IP hardcoded into network manager?
   My Requirements are,
3. I need my IPs to be in 192.168.x.x range.

Comment: Yes, the 10.42.0 is hardwired.

Answer (score 8):

I assume that you have shared your internet connection and the IP of 10.42.0.1/24 network has been assigned now after that do this to list all your connections

```
sudo nmcli c
```

[image]

I assume that you are sharing the internet on "Wired-Connection-1".

Take down the interface:

```
sudo nmcli c down Wired-Connection-1
```

Assign the ip4 IP that you wish to use.Iin your case I guess that will be `192.186.1.1/24`.

```
sudo nmcli c modify Wired-Connection-1 ipv4.address 192.168.1.1/24
```

Then bring up the interface:

```
sudo nmcli c up Wired-Connection-1
```

reference: *https://bhaskerv.blogspot.com/2016/06/network-maanget-changing-default-1042.html*